# sql permissions to a login user to further create logins and application roles

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server Express 2005.

I have only a single database to work with & create logins, users and grant permissions on this database only.

I created a database shopDB.

Then a login shopDBLogin.

Then I selected shopDB & created a user shopDBUser for shopDBLogin. The code is:

```
create database shopDB

use shopDB
create login shopDBLogin with password='_'  , default_database = shopDB

use shopDB
create user shopDBUser for login shopDBLogin
```

Now, i want to give permissions to shopDBUser to perform the following tasks:

--create 3 new logins L1,L2,L3 & 3 new users U1,U2,U3 inside these logins

--give permissions to U2,U3 to only insert in sql database

--create 3 application roles

How do i give permissions for these tasks to the user? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have to go with [db_securityadmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx).

Use [sp_addrolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) to hand out the role.

Example:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_securityadmin', 'shopDBUser'
```

If you just want shopDBUser to be able to make 'sub-users' to his own user: You can't do that with roles. I suggest creating a stored procedure that does this, granting the stored prcedure elevated permissions and then granting shopDBUser permissions to execute the stored procedure.

You'll have to make the neccesary checks in the stp yourself of course. Mostly because i THINK the concept of sub-users is simply not known in SQL.

EDIT:
Perhaps implement the concept of sub-users as a seperate table UserInfo. See in below example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_CreateSubUser]
(
    @SubUser nvarchar(200),
    @Pass nvarchar(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC('create login ' + @SubUser + ' with password=''' + @Pass + ''', default_database = shopDB')
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
    EXEC('create user ' + @SubUser + ' for login ' + @SubUser )
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', @SubUser
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', @SubUser
    EXECUTE AS OWNER

    INSERT [dbo].[UserInfo]
    ([UserName],[ParentUserName])
    VALUES
    (@SubUser, USER)
END
```

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh: yes sir, i want to give permission to user U1 to create users U2, U3 & then he grants them permissions to only insert into the sql database. then what to use?  please help me out with the code

Comment: @sqlchild: The EXECUTE AS clause, when applied to the procedure Vincent referenced, should do what he describes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh : sir, i want a Login L1 to create a new Login L2, is this possible? L2 will also be able to connect to the sql database.

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh ; sir what code should i write in the stored procedure about which you have talked about, please help

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh : sir, firstly i have to give permission to shopDBUser to create new Logins. how do i this, i mean the code?

Comment: @sqlchild : If you create a stored procedure with elevated permissions you don't need to grant shopDBUser db_securityadmin. I will elaborate my answer.

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh: sir, whats the difference in creating a table inside a dbo schema and inside a user defined schema?

Comment: @sqlchild: The schema's are mostly there for your organizational convenience. But there IS a neat trick if you associate a schema with a login. If you then DON'T specify a schema ([dbname]..[tablename]) it will first look for the table in the user's schema and THEN in dbo. That way you can customize a table for a specific user. (This should be a seperate question though).